How to configure in-memory-web-api in Angular to accommodate route parameters
I am trying to get my data service to accommodate route parameters.
  @Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
  })
  export class DataService implements InMemoryDbService {
  
  createDb(): {
    products: IProducts[],
    product: IProduct
  } {
    const products = ProductsData.products;
    const product = ProductsData.product;

    return { products, product };
  }
}

When I'm executing a route like products/123 I want the system to get the product collection. I've tried different approaches using the environment file and the product collection within the products-data.ts file, but I'm not having any luck. Are there examples available? For that matter, how should the data service be configured to accommodate query strings?

The property of the object you want to filter will be the key of the query string.
api/heroes/?name=${term}

Here we filter name of the object { id: 0, name: 'Zero' }.
Just search for "tour of heroes stackblitz" to get wide range of examples for you to use as reference.
Forked Stackblitz

Ok, I have succeeded in filtering based on a route parameter that matches a record ID. Two questions remain: 1) can a record ID be itemId or does if have to be just id, and 2) can query parameters be used to filter on a range, like all the records between a given from and to date?
